# How can you output something when login is completed? Django allauth

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a form that when the login button is clicked, it displays a login succesful message. Here is the thing, I want that when the "login" button is clicked, the user gets redirected and in the redirected page (which is the home page), it should show the message. How can you do this in Django allauth with their default themes?

I've tried doing:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
```

But the problem with this code is that the message appears each time, even when you reload the page.

Comment: You must use signals, when user logged in, intercept signal sending and use messages. Send it in context that's all.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893783/how-can-you-output-something-when-login-is-completed-django/65893984) by another user. Something fishy is going on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you output something when login is completed? Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893783/how-can-you-output-something-when-login-is-completed-django)

Comment: it is different.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this is to use Django's login signals and messaging framework.

First, in your `models.py` of the app that manages users (or somewhere that gets instantiated when your Django Project is started), you can do something like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.contrib import messages

def login_tasks(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    messages.add_message(
        request,
        messages.INFO,
        f"Welcome {user.username}, you have logged in.",
    }

user_logged_in.connect(login_tasks)
```

Then in your template:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

- More on Django's login signals: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals
- More on Django's messages framework: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/

Good luck!